# Traverse directed graph without "catching up"

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-traversal

I have a (acyclical) directed graph, which I want to traverse in the right order. [image]

The arrows indicate dependencies - a node should only be visited if all previous nodes are already visited.

I tried both a "depth first" and "breadth first" approach. (Not sure if I can call them exactly that, since it's not an actual tree).

"depth first":
[image]

"breadth first":
[image]

With both approaches, I don't get the proper order - the leftmost node is visited before another node is visited.

I think I see what's going wrong - the "breadth" is not so relevant, since there can be an arbitrarily number of nodes on each branch. Just not sure how to fix this?

**Edit: A right solution for my problem would be:**
[image]
**It should ensure that every arrow goes from a lower to a higher number**

Comment: Please show (as opposed to describe) what the "right order" for you example would be.

Comment: If you knew how many parents each node has, and decremented that count for every child of a visited node, you would know when a node is ready to be visited.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a queue of nodes to visit. Initially populate it with the starting vertex.

Associate a count of predecessors_visited for each node, initially 0.

Then, repeatedly:

- take a node from the queue
- increment predecessors_visited for all its descendants.
- add any descendant whose predecessors_visited == indegree to the queue.